# How to post data in CakePHP Controller requestAction method when called through API action?

Tags: php, json, http-post, httprequest, cakephp-2.x

I am working on a CakePHP 2.x (v2.8) application. I have created a controller (and the required action) for Rest API. Now I am able to successfully call the API from Postman. But from the API action, I am not able to use requestAction method properly. The data which I am trying to post is not posted properly. The data which was posted to API is still appearing in the request->data of the method specified in requestAction. I have mentioned sample dummy data to explain what is happening.

As per documentation, I have used 'data' as a key to array which needs to be posted to the requested action.
CakePHP version is 2.8, MySQL version is 5.7, PHP version is 5.4

One more thing I have observed is that, When the request body of the API (as called from PostMan) is in JSON (application/json), then this issue occurs. If in Postman, I set the request content type to "Text" or "Text(text/plain)", then it works as expected.

The link which I call via Postman is like below:

URL: localhost/my-app/CustomerApis/create.json

```
Post Request Body(example):
{
  'text' => 'Hello API!'
}
```

Content Type set to "JSON (application/json)"

```
// routes.php
Router::mapResources('customer_apis');
Router::parseExtensions('json', 'xml');



// Controller/CustomerApisController.php
<?php
// API controller and action

class CustomerApisController extends AppController {


    public function beforeFilter() {

        $this->Auth->allow();
        $this->request->data = $this->request->input("json_decode", true);
        // For example, Now $this->request->data becomes: array("text" => "Hello API!")

    }


    public function create() {
        $response = $this->requestAction(array('plugin' => null, 'controller' => 'Customers', 'action' => 'add'), array('data' => array('text' => 'Hello World!')));
        /* requestAction works but data is not posted correctly */
        }
    }


// Controller/CustomersController.php
/* Internal Application Controller and actions */

class CustomersController extends AppController {

    public function add() {

        pr($this->request->data);
        /* Here $this->request->data should be array('text' => 'Hello World!'), but instead it is still array("text" => "Hello API!") */
        return array('Success' => true);

    }

}

/*
Expected Result (when pr() in CustomersController.php): 

         Array(
            'text' => 'Hello World'!
         )
*/

/*
Actual Result: 

         Array(
            'text' => 'Hello API'!
         )
*/
```

Comment: Why does your url end with .json extension. Never saw that before

Comment: If the URL ends with .json extension, it gives JSON response, if it ends with xml, it gives XML response. I have figured out the issue by the way, this is happening because of below line in RequestHandlerComponent::startUp method :

    $controller->request->data = $input;

Comment: This code should not be run for the requested actions. That means actions called via Controller::requestAction method.